# Two different ways of defining a constructor

Tags: c++

Let's have two pieces of code. Each piece of code has two classes and those classes are very similar. The only difference is in defining constructors of class `B`.

First program:

```
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A( int x ) : val( x ) { cout << val << endl; }
    private:
        int val;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B( int x ) { instanceA( x ); }
    private:
        A instanceA;
};


int main()
{
    B instanceB( 5 );
}
```

Second program:

```
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A( int x ) : val( x ) { cout << val << endl; }
    private:
        int val;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B( int x ) : instanceA( x ) { }
    private:
        A instanceA;
};


int main()
{
    B instanceB( 5 );
}
```

The constructor of class `B` in the first program is defined as:

```
B( int x ) { instanceA( x ) }
```

The constructor of class `B` in the second program is defined as:

```
B( int x ) : instanceA( x ) { }
```

The first code is not working and the second one is working - 
**What's the difference in defining the constructor the first and the second way in this case and also in global?**

**EDIT**: Instead of `B( int x ) { instanceA( x ); }` needs to be `B( int x ) { instanceA = A( x ) }`

Comment: `B( int x ) { instanceA = A( x ) }` - This differs from the code above

Comment: @EdHeal fixed, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the 2nd case ([member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)), `instanceA` will be initialized by `A::A(int)` directly.

For the 1st case, `instanceA` will be initialized by `A::A()` (the default constructor) firstly, the body of the constructor will be executed later. Because `A` doesn't have a default constructor, it failed.

> Initialization order
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.
>   4) Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

And `instanceA(x);` won't do what you expected (i.e. call `A::A(int)` to initialize it), it will be parsed as `instanceA.operator()(x);` and won't compile since it's doesn't provide `operator()`.

Comment: And once `A` has a default constructor the first program will fail because `instanceA` is not a callable object.

Comment: So, as first, attributes of object are initialized by `member initializer list` and then the code in `{ }` is executed. If `object` is not initialized in `member initializer list` ( proper constructor is not called ), the compiling process fails?

EDIT: You have already edited post, that you. It was explained.

Comment: @lolofon Yes. "If object is not initialized in member initializer list ( proper constructor is not called ),", then the default ctor will be invoked firstly, and fails in this case because there's no default ctor for `A`. This is a common case to use member initializer list.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, my bad. Should be `instanceA = A( x )`

Answer (score 1):

```
 instanceA( x );
```

is not a function